# How to pass a search model into angular $http.get

Tags: angularjs

how do I do this without manually specifying the url by building a string

```
var memberSearchModel = {
        SearchBy: "Name",
        SearchValue: "jaredites"

    };
    dataFactory.getMembers = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + memberSearchModel);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter is the url, second is the data:

```
var memberSearchModel = {
    SearchBy: "Name",
    SearchValue: "jaredites"

};
dataFactory.getMembers = function () {
    return $http.get(urlBase, memberSearchModel);
};
```

See [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs

Comment: Would you happen to know why the search model on the web api side is coming through with null values?